Why isn't my post install script executing?
Not sure what am I missing.
I have created a 2GP managed package that includes a post installation script. I am trying to create records when I install the package. But it seems the script is not working, I'm m not receiving any error or any mail as well. I am using VS code and sfdx commands to create the package.
Could anyone help?
Class:
global class PostInstallScript implements InstallHandler {
    global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
        try {
            loadDataFromStaticResource();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sendErrorNotification(e);
        }
    }

    private void loadDataFromStaticResource() {
        StaticResource sampleDataResource = [SELECT Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'SampleData'];
        String sampleData = sampleDataResource.Body.toString();

        List<Object> jsonData = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(sampleData);
        List<myNameSpace__test_Post_Install__c> records = new List<myNameSpace__test_Post_Install__c>();

        for (Object obj : jsonData) {
            Map<String, Object> recordMap = (Map<String, Object>) obj;
            myNameSpace__test_Post_Install__c record = new myNameSpace__test_Post_Install__c();
            record.Name = (String) recordMap.get('Name');
            record.myNameSpace__purpose__c = (String) recordMap.get('myNameSpace__purpose__c');
            records.add(record);
        }

        if (!records.isEmpty()) {
            insert records;
        }
    }

    private void sendErrorNotification(Exception e) {
        String subject = 'Post-Install Script Error';
        String body = 'An error occurred during the post-install script execution: ' + e.getMessage();
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {'myEmail19@gmail.com'});
        mail.setSubject(subject);
        mail.setPlainTextBody(body);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}

project.json
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "postInstallClass": "PostInstallScript",
      "postInstallScript": "PostInstallScript",
      "package": "TestPostInstallScript",
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "default": true,
      "versionDescription": "Testing post install script"
    }
  ],
  "name": "testProjectforPostInstallation",
  "namespace": "myNameSpace",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "61.0",
  "packageAliases": {
    "TestPostInstallScript": "0Ho6m0000001P3XXXX",
    ...
    }
    }


We specified our post install class so it included the namespace. So I suggest setting it to "myNameSpace.PostInstallScript" (according to your example).
